# Error while performing operation on DatetimeIndexResampler type

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I have a time-series data frame and want to find difference between the date in each record and the last (maximum) date within that data-frame. But getting error - TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'DatetimeIndex' and 'SeriesGroupBy'. Seems from the error that data frame is not in the 'right' type to be allowed to have these operations allowed. How can I avoid this or possibly cast the data in some other format to be able to do the operation. Below is sample code which reproduces the error

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[54.7,36.3,'2010-07-20'],[54.7,36.3,'2010-07-21'],[52.3,38.7,'2010-07-26'],[52.3,38.7,'2010-07-30']],
                  columns=['col1','col2','date'])
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
df.index = df.date
df = df.resample('D')
print(type(df))
diff = (df.date.max() - df.date).values
```

Comment: What is expected output? Why is here `resample` ?

Comment: A List of differences between each record's date and maximum date in the data frame. For example from the example I gave if I print diff[0] -> output should be 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need create `DatetimeIndex` first by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), so if aggregate by `max` then get consecutive values:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[54.7,36.3,'2010-07-20'],
                   [54.7,36.3,'2010-07-21'],
                   [52.3,38.7,'2010-07-26'],
                   [52.3,38.7,'2010-07-30']],
              columns=['col1','col2','date'])

df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)

df1 = df.set_index('date').resample('D').max()
#alternative if not duplicated datetimes
#df1 = df.set_index('date').asfreq('D')
print (df1)
            col1  col2
date                  
2010-07-20  54.7  36.3
2010-07-21  54.7  36.3
2010-07-22   NaN   NaN
2010-07-23   NaN   NaN
2010-07-24   NaN   NaN
2010-07-25   NaN   NaN
2010-07-26  52.3  38.7
2010-07-27   NaN   NaN
2010-07-28   NaN   NaN
2010-07-29   NaN   NaN
2010-07-30  52.3  38.7
```

Then subtract max value of index with itself and convert timedeltas to days by [`TimedeltaIndex.days`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.TimedeltaIndex.days.html):

```
df1['diff'] =  (df1.index.max() - df1.index).days
print (df1)
            col1  col2  diff
date                        
2010-07-20  54.7  36.3    10
2010-07-21  54.7  36.3     9
2010-07-22   NaN   NaN     8
2010-07-23   NaN   NaN     7
2010-07-24   NaN   NaN     6
2010-07-25   NaN   NaN     5
2010-07-26  52.3  38.7     4
2010-07-27   NaN   NaN     3
2010-07-28   NaN   NaN     2
2010-07-29   NaN   NaN     1
2010-07-30  52.3  38.7     0
```

Comment: Gives an error - AttributeError: Cannot access callable attribute 'rsub' of 'SeriesGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method

Comment: @SanchitLatawa - but in my code is no `resample`, no `groupby`

Comment: But I want to resample the time series to get daily data , hence the issue.

Comment: @SanchitLatawa - there are times in date column?

Comment: Dates in the 'date' column, I am explicitly casting is using -> pd.to_datetime(df.date) in my test script

Comment: @SanchitLatawa - I am really confused. Still not understand of `resample` here, because if use `df1 = df.resample('D').date.max()` then it return same values like `df.date`, so difference is always 0. :(

Comment: @SanchitLatawa - only there are added missing datetimes.

Comment: @SanchitLatawa - Also close, what need is `diff = df.resample('D', on='date')['date'].transform('max') - df['date']` - but it is same problem in sample data - all data difference are 0

Comment: 1) I am re sampling to fill in the missing days data , so that I have daily data to analyze 2) I think the issue is ->  df = df.resample('D',on='date') , the df that is returned does not work with data frame functions , e.g df.head() is going to throw an error ,as type(df) is now -> DatetimeIndexResampler. Whereas if you look at the link -https://machinelearningmastery.com/resample-interpolate-time-series-data-python/ and search for code under header 'Upsample Shampoo Sales' that seems to work for the author . Maybe it is some recent change to resample which is causing this ?

Comment: @SanchitLatawa - OK, but maybe not understand each other. Can you add expected output `diff` to question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202640/discussion-between-sanchit-latawa-and-jezrael).